# Click() on asp.net linkbutton using selenium automation script not working

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium automation and using C# to writing the automation script.

When I am clicking on Linkbutton it is not navigating to another page.

I am using this code for clicking on the link button.

```
public IWebDriver driver;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ ClientidLinkbutton ")).Click();
```

I used Mozila firefox for seeing through the INSPECTOR, and I  got  an anchor tag which is given below.

It is the Inner HTML :

`<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ClientidLinkbutton " href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ClientidLinkbutton ','')" style="color:Blue;">Value of Link button</a>`

What is the problem and how can we navigate to another page using selenium automation script.

Comment: Not getting exception ,  it processes page after clicking but after some second processing get stepped and nothing happens ..

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the code, both segments of code have at least once space in the id values, possibly giving you the errors.

Try the following:

```
public IWebDriver driver;
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ClientidLinkbutton")).Click();
```

And for the HTML:

```
 <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ClientidLinkbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ClientidLinkbutton','')" style="color:Blue;">Value of Link button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Value of Link button")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ ClientidLinkbutton']")).Click();
```

Comment: Both option are not working for me. Same page is loading again after clicking.

Comment: and when you clicking the button everything working ?

Comment: This code is executed. But there is no further process. Test successfully executed. Same page loaded again. It should go to the next page. Why it is not working . In real time it is working correctly. But when I am applying automation not going to next page.

Comment: can u try it in firefox ?

Comment: My application is for Internet explorer. No requirement for Firefox.

Comment: This is how I am navigating to demo.aspx.

 

LinkButton is in grid , I am passing a commandname and handling it in Vb.net code
<asp:LinkButton ForeColor="blue"CommandName="NavigatetoGeneral" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(data)%>'

                                          CommandArgument='<%#(DataBinder.Eval(data))%>'  ID="lnkSENumber" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

 

 

VB Code for  handling event

 

Protected Sub grid_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgrHomeGrid.RowCommand

      

If e.CommandName = "NavigatetoDemo" T

Comment: If e.CommandName = "NavigatetoDemo" Then

Response.Redirect("Demo.aspx", False)

End If

Comment: I tried it with a demo application ,it's working with it. But with my application its not working

Comment: Thanks for helping. That issue is solved. I got the solution for the same. That was a synchronization problem. My script was not synchronized. After giving some time to wait for loading the link , its working perfectly.